# Why are those equivalent transformations of inverse functions not the same thing?

Tags: inverse

Why are $\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{g}+\frac{1}{b}$ and $f=g+b$ not the same thing?

Comment: Try $1/2 + 1/2$. Now try $2 + 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $\frac{1}{f}=\frac{g+b}{bg}$ and then we have $f=\frac{bg}{b+g}$

Comment: Stared too long at it =) , sorry for the question.